# Overall pressure and movement in Earth making heat because of gravity

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, gravity

There are three sources of heat in the Earth's core, impacts of the planet when it was created (impacts made heat), radioactive decay of elements, and the extreme amounts of pressure and friction created from rocks pressing down on each other because of gravity. The last of which creates heat only because of gravity. This is a violation of conservation of energy in my mind. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: A hydro power station works because of gravity. Is that also a violation of conservation of energy in your mind?

Comment: not exactly, that requires work first from the sun.

Comment: Your 3rd source of heat converts gravitational potential energy to heat. So what's the difference? BTW, there's also gravitational heating due to tidal stress, as Jupiter's moon Io demonstrates quite spectacularly. The Earth's crust gets gets a little tidal heating from the Moon, maybe the mantle does too. I don't think the solid core gets much heat that way.

Comment: but that potential energy wouldn't be there if not for gravity and therefore gravity is creating energy just by existing and creating that potential energy.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're getting at. Your 3rd source of heat works by stuff moving downwards. You don't get any heat produced by stuff sitting at a static height in a gravitational field.

Comment: But aren't there convection currents that cause such material to rotate around and create free friction heat from gravity?

Comment: You only get convection if there's a temperature differential, so those convection cycles are driven by the temperature difference between the bottom & top of the mantle. One heat source I forgot to mention before is the latent heat released as the liquid outer core crystallizes at the inner core boundary. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient for details.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing gravity does not "make heat". Heat is *energy transfer* between objects solely due to a temperature difference between them. The proper term is internal energy, the kinetic part of which is reflected in temperature.

From everything I've read, the two principle causes of the extremely high temperatures at the core of the earth are (1) the remnants of the formation of the planet and (2) radioactive decay of the elements. I have read that pressure, regardless of the source, is not responsible for the high temperatures at the core of the earth.

UPDATE:

Per your citing of the Scientific American article, we can include a third source: friction due to the movement of iron rich materials sinking to the core. However, I still have not yet seen pressure as a reason for the high core temperatures.

Hope this helps.

Comment: k ill go find the source wait up

Comment: @Locomotive38 Fair enough. If you find  something reliable, we will both learn something.

Comment: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-is-the-earths-core-so/

Comment: ah yes I will send you one that cites pressure also right away